# Capture still image from recorded video

Tags: photos

I'm using a Motorola Moto g5 with latest Google photos. I try to find a way to select and export still images from my recorded videos.

Preferably within Google Photos but could be another app as well.

Comment: Pick up from [Izzy's list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_video)